# Select distinct values from multiple columns

Tags: sql, distinct

I had a table (Some_Table) with two columns:
A      B 
-------------------
1 test
2 test
3 test1 
4 test1

i would like to return **DISTINCT** values for column B and it's associated value in column A (first in distinct set), so something like this:

A     B
-----------
1 test
3 test1

**What is the sql?**

Comment: In this example, there are two first column values for each second column. You want only the least value for each second column value?

Comment: You have a good answer by Mark below, only a note here; saying `first in distinct set` is wrong. sets are unordered, if you want to talk about order you have to specify in respect to what (own value, some other columns value, etc...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select min(A),B
  from table
 group by B
```